# project of type maven-archetype tries to download plexus-tools:1.1

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I have a simple archetype project. When using even mvn clean, it tries to download plexus-utils:1.1, which is prohibited from my company's repo due to vulnerabilities.

I have been through the various artefacts checking for a dependency on this version and found none. The only dependency I can find is on plexus-utils:3.2.0.

On my personal laptop, if I delete all versions of plexus-utils from my local repo, it downloads 1.1 before downloading other versions later (for the clean plugin, or the archetype plugin etc).

Can anyone help me work out why it tries to download that version of plexus-utils?

pom.xml

```
...
    <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
...

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
                <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

result of mvn -X clean

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T19:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\no-space-paths\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core

... snip ...

[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core

... snip ...

[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.

... snip ...

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=759600, ConflictMarker.markTime=341900, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=804800, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=613100, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3014800, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=63887200, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=8607800}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:jar:3.1.2:
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar (169 kB at 218 kB/s)

... snip (downloads as normal) ...

[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:3.1.2
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:3.1.2
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:3.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:jar:3.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project test:test:maven-archetype:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:3.1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]]
[DEBUG] Created new class realm project>test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Populating class realm project>test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging:jar:3.1.2
```

And the corporate version fails because it cannot download plexus-utils:1.1. This is all before it actually starts to process the clean goal.

So, for some reason, it has resolved the dependencies for archetype-packaging and decided that it requires plexus-utils:1.1. What does the `:runtime` mean in the list of dependencies?  -- edited to say, I can see that `:runtime` must be the scope of the dependency, but it isn't declared anywhere.

But if I look at archetype-packaging, there is nothing in the pom or jar that suggests to me that it should use plexus-utils:1.1.

archetype-packaging-3.1.2.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>

  <name>Maven Archetype Packaging</name>
  <description>'maven-archetype' packaging configuration for archetypes.</description>

</project>
```

maven-archetype-3.1.2.pom

```
  <dependencyManagement>

... snip ...

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
...
```

Really the only thing in the archetype-packaging jar file is plexus\components.xml. I suppose it could be something in here, but there is no indication from the dependency collection that it is using any of these and there is no clean goal specified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
      <role-hint>maven-archetype</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
      <configuration>
        
        <phases>
          <process-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources</process-resources>
          <process-test-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:testResources</process-test-resources>
          <package>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar</package>
          <integration-test>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:integration-test</integration-test>
          <install>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install,
            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:update-local-catalog
          </install>
          
          <deploy>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy</deploy>
        </phases>
        
      </configuration>
    </component>

    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
      <role-hint>maven-archetype</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <type>maven-archetype</type>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
      </configuration>
    </component>

  </components>
</component-set>
```

Comment: Why do you use `maven-archetype` as a parent?

Comment: I am not, that is the parent of archetype-packaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is (somewhat obscure) functionality of Maven 3 to be compatible with Maven 2. Any plugin (or extension) that does not declare an explicit dependency on plexus-utils will have an implicit dependency on plexus-utils:1.1 added.

You can see what I think of this decision here: [archetype-packaging.jar:3.1.2 requires org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6965)